# Cant get fbrell codes work out fbrell site

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

in short words i want to use this method of fbrell site and make it work [Generate Token](https://www.fbrell.com/auth/offline-access-token)

i had alot of trials but failed. all work until it get to update the `<pre>` code with the access token . it totally don't work
any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Offline-access has been deprecated and has been replaced by long-lived access tokens.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/roadmap/completed-changes/offline-access-removal/

Comment: i know . ididnt mean that i mean echoing generated access in pre whatever the scope. gor example use publish-